# Working with multidimensional arrays from JSON/RPC APIs in PHP

Tags: php, api, multidimensional-array

I'm working with some JSON based APIs in RPC style and I'm getting this multidimensional arrays after interacting with the APIs via some PHP wrappers:

```
Array
  (
  [ok] => 1
  [taskgroup] => Array
      (
        [task_1] => Array
            (
                [id] => task_1
                [name] => Task 1
                [url] => /tasks/1/
                [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                [img] => http://example.net/mypic1442421.png
                [related_tasks] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => task_18
                    )
            )

        [task_2] => Array
            (
                [id] => task_2
                [name] => Task 2
                [url] => /tasks/2/
                [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                [img] => http://example.net/mypic1442421.png
                [related_tasks] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => task_9
                        [1] => task_23
                    )
            )
     )
)
```

My question is, how can I go through this multi-dimensional arrays? Is there some related methods for this kind of md-array responses? More concretely -to take on some example that could bring light to this thing- how can I print a list of all the images and url like `taskArray[][task_n][img] -  taskArray[][task_n][url]`? --task_n can be any non-sequential alphanumeric value

I tried some recursive methods I found here but without luck, please excuse if I'm asking again the same thing. And excuse the n00bness.

Comment: Look into the manual on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and the [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, that array would be processed with code something like this:

```
if (!empty($apiResult['OK']) && !empty($apiResult['taskgroup'])) {
    foreach ($apiResult['taskGroup'] as $taskId => $task) {
        $id = $task['id'];
        $img = $task['img'];
        $url = $task['url'];
        printf("Image: %s, URL: %s\n", $img, $url);
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this makes total sense.. in any case I could make a function -to create a subset Array- like this?

`function imgList($apiResult) { 
    $newArray=array();
    $i=0;
    if (!empty($apiResult['OK']) && !empty($apiResult['taskgroup'])) {
        foreach ($apiResult['taskGroup'] as $taskId => $task) {
            $newArray[$i][id] = $task['id'];
            $newArray[$i][img] = $task['img'];
            $newArray[$i][url] = $task['url'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
    else {
 return $response="nada";
    }
    }`

Comment: It's hard to debug the function in the comment, but yes, you can do that.

Comment: It worked flawlessly! Thanks for a concise explanation, I was drowning in a glass of water+